# pyserial access com port on remote computer via IP

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to access a serial device on a network computer. The device is connected via USB-Serial cable and is assigned COM8 port.

I tried to use:

```
import serial
ser = serial.serial_for_url("socket://10.10.10.152:///dev/ttyCOM8")
```

Which is wrong. I am pretty sure serail_for_url will only accept port number. But I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: What "network computer"? Unless your network computer runs a software implementing RFC2217 or has a service that connects /dev/ttyCOM8 to a specific TCP/IP port, this is not going to work.

Comment: @Codo. I might be wrong. But i was under impression that pyserial supports communication over TCP/IP i.e. local ports can be accessed via IP address from remote machine. I thought serial_for_url is for that, but can't figure out exact settings

Comment: Yes, pyserial supports communication over TCP/IP. But the target computer needs to implement the "last mile", from the TCP port to the serial port / USB port.

Comment: @Codo. Got it. Thanks to you i knew what I need to look for. I found TCP-COM software that enabled me to commicate. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @goryef: what software that you find? I am having a similar problem...

Comment: @westr TCP-COM works fine for me